# Angular 4 TypeScript JSON parsing from HTTP response

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I'm trying to get the JSON object inside the `reformatGITResponse` method but I'm getting exceptions. I tried various ways but couldn't succeed. 
How should I get the object so that I can iterate on it ?
On what parameter of the Response object should I get and parse JSON and how?

I'm trying to parse the JSON located at the following URL:

https://api.github.com/repos/angular/angular.js/commits

```
<p>d3 works!</p>
<p *ngIf="!loading">{{authorNames}}
</p>
<button (click)="getCommitData()">button1</button>

import {Component, OnInit, OnDestroy} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpModule, Http, Jsonp} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import * as $ from 'jquery';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-d3',
  templateUrl: './d3.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./d3.component.css']
})
export class D3Component implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  user: String = 'angular';
  repo: String = 'angular.js';
  data: String;
  error: String;
  url: string;
  loading = true;
  output: String;
  authorNames: String[];
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.repo = 'angular.js';
    this.user = 'angular';
    this.url = 'https://api.github.com/repos/' + this.user +
      '/' +
      this.repo +
      '/commits';
  }

  constructor(private http: Http) {
    this.repo = 'angular.js';
    this.user = 'angular';
    this.url = 'https://api.github.com/repos/' + this.user +
      '/' +
      this.repo +
      '/commits';
  }

  humanReadableDate(d: Date): String {
    return d.getUTCMonth() + 1 + '/' + d.getUTCDate();
  }

  reformatGITResponse(data: any): any {
    let index = 0;
    const obj = JSON.parse(data.json());
    obj.array.every(currentItem =>
      this.authorNames[index++] = currentItem
    );
    return data;
  }

  handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
    console.error('An error occurred', error);
    return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
  }

  getCommitData(): Promise<any> {
    console.log(this.url);
    return this.http.get(this.url).toPromise()
      .then(response => {
        this.loading = false;
        this.output = this.reformatGITResponse(response);
        console.log(this.output);
      }).catch(this.handleError);
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    console.log('destroyed');
  }
}
```

Comment: the .json() method that you are calling in reformatGITResponse parses the json from the request. You shouldn't need to use JSON.parse(). You are essentially trying to parse twice

Comment: yes thak you its working.